# Cant print items in CSV

Tags: python

When I open sdata.csv file it will not iterate, no error is shown simply not printing. Why could this be? I even did print(g) and it shows its reading properly. I also am trying to write data to the same file and the same blank file occurs with only the heading in it.

```
import urllib.request as request
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import requests
import demjson
import csv
import time

req = Request('https://api.gameslabs.net/1.0.0/exchange', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
with request.urlopen(req) as response:
    if response.getcode() == 200:
        source = response.read()
        data = json.loads(source)
    else:
        print('An error occurred while attempting to retrieve data from the API.')

y = json.dumps(data)
x = json.loads(y)

f = csv.writer(open("item-com.csv", "w+"))

# Write CSV Header, If you dont need that, remove this line
f.writerow(["symbol", "buy_game", "buy_item", "buy_name", "sell_game", "sell_item", "sell_name"])

for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["symbol"],
                x["buy"]["game"],
                x["buy"]["item"],
                x["buy"]["name"],
                x["sell"]["game"],
                x["sell"]["item"],
                x["sell"]["name"]])

o = csv.DictReader(open("item-com.csv"))
for row in o:
    print(row['buy_name'])

req2 = Request('https://api.gameslabs.net/1.0.0/exchange/symbol/MS_IRON_PICKAXE/candles?timeFrame=day',
               headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
with request.urlopen(req2) as response:
    if response.getcode() == 200:
        source2 = response.read()
        data2 = json.loads(source2)
    else:
        print('An error occurred while attempting to retrieve data from the API.')

xdum = json.dumps(data2)
bdum = json.loads(xdum)

ged = csv.writer(open("sdata.csv", "w+"))

ged.writerow(["timestamp", "low", "open", "close", "high", "volume"])

for bdum in bdum:
    ged.writerow([bdum["timestamp"],
                  bdum["low"],
                  bdum["open"],
                  bdum["close"],
                  bdum["high"]])

g = csv.DictReader(open("sdata.csv"))

for row in g:
    print(row['timestamp'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing and reading from the same files. However, you don't ensure the file is closed in between. If you use a context manager it will take care of that for you. I notice you are using context managers for url respones.

I've modified your slightly code to use context managers for file management:

```
...
with open("item-com.csv", "w+") as csv_file:
    f = csv.writer(csv_file)
    # Write CSV Header, If you dont need that, remove this line
    f.writerow(["symbol", "buy_game", "buy_item", "buy_name", "sell_game", "sell_item", "sell_name"])

    for x in x:
        f.writerow([x["symbol"],
                    x["buy"]["game"],
                    x["buy"]["item"],
                    x["buy"]["name"],
                    x["sell"]["game"],
                    x["sell"]["item"],
                    x["sell"]["name"]])

with open("item-com.csv") as csv_file:
    o =  csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in o:
        print(row['buy_name'])

req2 = Request('https://api.gameslabs.net/1.0.0/exchange/symbol/MS_IRON_PICKAXE/candles?timeFrame=day',
               headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
with request.urlopen(req2) as response:
    if response.getcode() == 200:
        source2 = response.read()
        data2 = json.loads(source2)
    else:
        print('An error occurred while attempting to retrieve data from the API.')

xdum = json.dumps(data2)
bdum = json.loads(xdum)

with open("sdata.csv", "w+") as csv_file:
    ged = csv.writer(csv_file)
    ged.writerow(["timestamp", "low", "open", "close", "high", "volume"])

    for bdum in bdum:
        ged.writerow([bdum["timestamp"],
                      bdum["low"],
                      bdum["open"],
                      bdum["close"],
                      bdum["high"]])

with open("sdata.csv") as csv_file:
    g = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in g:
        print(row['timestamp'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing line by line to text file try this way. This method reduces repetitive i/o and doesn't have to keep the file open for long time.

```
lst = []
for x in x:
    tmpTuple = ([x["symbol"],
            x["buy"]["game"],
            x["buy"]["item"],
            x["buy"]["name"],
            x["sell"]["game"],
            x["sell"]["item"],
            x["sell"]["name"]])
     lst.append(tmpTuple)

#outside loop create a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

#this is several options to save
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: When doing what you suggested the first line of the file is subsequntly cut off at the start? https://pastebin.com/Sajy9p6r 

https://gyazo.com/5de8d3079c48814a507b7691e7b5690c

Also this does not answer my question why
`g = csv.DictReader(open("sdata.csv"))

for q in g:
    print(q['timestamp'])`

Does not work.